# C++ : I have two array where the first and last element have the same memory adress

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem issue with adress memory of an array. I have an array A[4], and an array B[4]. I notice that when I print &A[0] and &B[4], these two have the same adress memory. I don't know why and how to fix it. This is my code in c++

```
#include < iostream>


int main()
{

    int a[4];
    int b[4];




for (int i=0; i<=4; i++)
{

    std::cout << &a[i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << &b[i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "___________" << std::endl;
    a[i] = i;
    b[i] =i;
}

printf("a:b\n");
for (int i=0; i<=4; i++)
    printf("%d:%d\n", a[i], b[i]);

}
```

This is what it print :

0x61fe00

0x61fdf0

---

0x61fe04

0x61fdf4

---

0x61fe08

0x61fdf8

---

0x61fe0c

0x61fdfc

---

0x61fe10

0x61fe00

---

a:b

4:0

1:1

2:2

3:3

4:4

I don't know why a[0] an b[4] have the same adress memory. Thank you.

Comment: How many elements are in your array? `int a[4];` so 4 elements. And how many elements do you try to access? `i=0`, `i=1`, `i=2`, `i=3`, `i=4` - total 5 elements.

Comment: Oh thank you! I wrote i <= 4 instead of i < 4 within my for loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because a,b are local variables and pushed to stack sequentially i.e b is pushed after a. So when you print address of b[4] (just out of boundary of array b, as b[3] is the last item of b) it actually pointing to the address of starts of array a, i.e. a[0].

Comment: Okay thanks, now I understand my mistake : b[4] doesn't exit. But I still don't understand why b[4] is pointing to a[0] adress memory? Is it just by accident?

Comment: No. array a is pushed to stack then array b. so internally in stack addresses would be like b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3],a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]. So when you print b[4] (means 4 items shift from b[0]) is the address of a[0]

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of the stack memory allocation...

Answer (score 0):

b[4] is outside the memory assigned for b, so it could well be that b[4] refers to the start of a, a[0]. B begins at b[0] and ends at b[3].

Answer (score 0):

You loop is wrong - it loops over **five** elements while your arrays only have **four** elements. Since `b` follows `a` in the stack, the address after the last element of `a` is in fact the first element of `b`.

To make long story short - there's nothing wrong with the arrays, you just need to loop correctly by changing the `<=` condition to `<`:

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    // Here ---^
    std::cout << &a[i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << &b[i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "___________" << std::endl;
    a[i] = i;
    b[i] =i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`b[4]` is not an element of `b`, it is one past then end of `b`. You can get a pointer to it, so `&b[4]` is ok, but it is undefined behaviour to use it otherwise, so the assignment `b[i] = i` with `i` at 4 means anything can happen

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for the one-index-past-the-end of the array to have the same memory address as another object.

> I don't know why and how to fix it.

Don't attempt to access outside the bounds of the array. The index 4 is beyond the last valid index.